# Python: Tkinter Scrollbar and Treeview Selection Synchronization

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have a scrollbar attached to a treeview.

```
    self.lst_shots = ttk.Treeview(
        self,
        height=7,
        selectmode="browse"
    )
    self.lst_shots["column"] = (
        "Shot",
        "Player",
    )
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.map(
        "Treeview",
        background=[("selected", "yellow")],
        foreground=[("selected", "black")],
    )
    self.lst_shots.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
    self.lst_shots.column("Shot", anchor=CENTER, width=20)
    self.lst_shots.column("Player", anchor=CENTER, width=100)
    self.lst_shots.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_lst_shots_sel_change)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
    scrollbar.config(command=self.lst_shots.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=4, column=6, rowspan=4, columnspan=1, sticky="wns")
    self.lst_shots.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    scrollbar.config(command=self.lst_shots.yview)
```

It's working well but If I programmatically move the current selection of my treeview from the code by calling `self.display_shot(Shot(index=14))`:

```
    def treeview_get_item(self, treeview, indexcolumn: int, value_to_find):
        found = None
        for child in treeview.get_children():
            if (
                value_to_find == treeview.item(child)["values"][indexcolumn]
            ):  # compare strings in  lower cases.
                found = child
        return found

    def display_shot(self, sel_shot: Shot):
        # focus on treeview current shot
        sel_item = self.treeview_get_item(self.lst_shots, 0, sel_shot.index)
        self.lst_shots.focus(sel_item)
        self.lst_shots.selection_set(sel_item)
```

I'd like the scrollbar to follow the move. For example, if the height of the treeview is 7 and the item is in position 14 the scrollbar should move there so it is visible on screen.
How can I manually move the scrollbar?

Comment: What is `Shot()`? There is function `.see(item)` to make the `item` visible.

Comment: a class Shot() with an attribute index. I use Shot.index as a value.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it with **yview_moveto**. Probably the code can be optimized.

```
def treeview_get_item(self, treeview, indexcolumn: int, value_to_find):
  found = None
  ix = 0
  for ix, child in enumerate(treeview.get_children()):
    if (
        value_to_find == treeview.item(child)["values"][indexcolumn]
    ):  # compare strings in  lower cases.
        found = child
  return found, ix

def display_shot(self, sel_shot: Shot):

  # focus on treeview current shot
  sel_item, sel_item_ix = self.treeview_get_item(
    self.lst_shots, 0, sel_shot.index
  )
  self.lst_shots.focus(sel_item)
  self.lst_shots.selection_set(sel_item)
  self.lst_shots.yview_moveto(
    int(sel_item) / (len(self.lst_shots.get_children()) - 1)
  )
```